# WooCommerce price position - variable product

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to move position of pice in wordpress in plugin WooCommerce. In normal product its without problems as you can see here: http://beta.gaumaya.sk/?product=produkts but in variable product its almost imposiible i am trying to do it for hours right now. Here is how it looks http://beta.gaumaya.sk/?product=produkt I really need to move that price next to title. My functions.php file: `add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary_geril', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary_geril', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 5 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary_geril', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 20 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary_geril', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );`

content-single-product.php : http://pastebin.com/2DZPnnfP . How can this little thing be changed?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing your `content-product.php` from your theme and reverting back to WooCommerce's default templates. The price is pretty near the title by default.

[image]

There is no need to create your own action hook `do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary_geril' );`? when you can simply unhook the functions you don't want from the existing hook using [`remove_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action)?